# Trying to integrate Keycloak into my drupal site, using openid-connect. Getting error

Tags: openid-connect, drupal-9, keycloak-connect

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException: Some mandatory parameters are missing ("openid_connect_client") to generate a URL for route "openid_connect.redirect_controller_redirect". in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 181 of C:\xampp\htdocs\test\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator.php).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this thing resolved @anushka ?

Comment: Yes, Its resolved. Composer update helped.